# Sitecore 8 Custom Icons without using zip file

Tags: icons, zip, sitecore

Adding custom icons in Sitecore requires the following step:

3. Zip it is all. The name of archive should be the same as the containing folder (MyIcons.zip);
4. Upload the zip file by the path which was mentioned above: \sitecore\shell\Themes\Standard.

The problem is when I need more icons I need to add the icon and zip the file again. Is there a way to avoid this or make this maintainable without using zip file?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly specify the URL of the icon you wish to use in the `Icon` field of the item. This can be an image on disk:

[image: Icon from file]

Or it can be an image from the Media Library:

[image: Thumbnail from Media Library]

I would recommend using the format such as: `/-/media/F8C69CCD422C40AC843D2E4144F16964.ashx?thn=1`

This ensures that the icon used is of thumbnail size (the `thn=1` parameter) and by using the guid of the media item it means that the icons can be moved/restructured without having to update the Icon fields.

In both these cases, you need to manually enter the path of the icon file, you cannot specify it using the icon selector dialog.